# OpenApi Generator and Inheritance Problem

Tags: swift, openapi, openapi-generator

Given the following abstract .Net Core C# pseudo code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public string? BaseMessage { get; set; }
}

public class OneClass: BaseClass 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TwoClass: OneClass
{
  public string? TwoClassPropertyName { get; set; }
}

public class ThreeClass : TwoClass
{
  public bool ThreeClassNiceBool { get; set; }
}
```

In my .NetCore project I have configured Swagger as this:

```html
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.UseAllOfForInheritance();
        });
```

Using swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.41 back to version swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.30 produces fine correct code for typescript-angular, php, #c BUT except swift5.
The Swift5 Generator produces this:

```html
public struct ThreeClass: Codable, JSONEncodable, Hashable {

    public var threeClassNiceBool: Bool?
    public var baseMessage: String?

    public init(threeClassNiceBool: Bool? = nil, baseMessage: String? = nil) {
        self.threeClassNiceBool = threeClassNiceBool
        self.baseMessage = baseMessage
    }
    
    // and so on
}
```

There is missing everything inherited from TwoClass and OneClass. What I am missing to get correct inheritance?